# referenceError: process is not defined at Object.config

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to use the key_id from the .env file in my app.jsx file but its showing :referenceError: process is not defined at Object.config in the console

Here is the React Code

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './style'
import { Crisp } from "crisp-sdk-web";



import { Navbar, Hero, Business, Billing, CardDeal, CTA, Footer } from './components'
// import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    
    Crisp.configure(process.env.REACT_APP_CRISP_WEBSITE_ID);
  }, []);
  return (

    <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden">
      <div className={`${styles.paddingX} ${styles.flexCenter}`}>
        <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={`bg-primary ${styles.flexStart}`}>
        <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <Hero />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={`bg-primary ${styles.paddingX} ${styles.flexStart}`}>
        <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          {/* remove stats */}
          <Business />
          <Billing />
          <CardDeal />

          <CTA />
          <Footer />


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Whenever I am  removing the import statement and config statement ,the code is working properly but then error related to process after importing the module . Also .env file is created in root directory and the variable is also stored correctly .

Comment: What do you need dotenv for? `create-react-app` parses `.env` file by default. `dotenv` file cannot be used in the browser